# Find common node from collections of ids

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have users connected to chat node like this

```
(u: User)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(c:Chat)
```

I need to avoid multiple chats with the same members.
So when someone create a group chat, I check if there is not a chat with the same members already.

the closest solution would be

```
MATCH (member)-[m:MEMBER_OF]->(c:Chat)
        WHERE member.id IN {members}
        WITH c.chatId as chatId, count(DISTINCT m) as nbR
        WHERE nbR = {nbMembers}
        RETURN chatId
```

with members [122, 233, 33] and nbMembers members.size = 3

This solution find all the chats connected to those members with 3 members (but not all togeter), it doesn't find the chat with the 3 members connected to it.

I didn't find a way with ALL or FILTER either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
MATCH (member)-[m:MEMBER_OF]->(c:Chat)
WITH c, member
ORDER BY member.id
WITH c, collect(member.id) AS member_ids
WHERE member_ids = {nbMembers}
RETURN c.chatId
```

Also, you should sort the value of nbMembers before it's passed to the query

Comment: Collect is what I want but this query raise an error because member is undefined in the ORDER BY. If we add it to the with clause then the we have a row per member. My solution is to use ALL(m in member_ids where m IN {members}"]) for the where clause and I don't need to sort anymore

Comment: I also need to compare array size otherwise I can find chat where x,y,z are members when I only look for x,y because x,y is IN x,y,z

Comment: Good point.  I've also just editing my question with an extra `WITH` which I think might make my solution work